# S3 presigned download url immediately expired, why?

Tags: amazon-s3

I have app that generates presigned url (using java sdk generatePresignedUrl method).
Everything works on one environment (@ EU_central_1 server), but the same app published on other environment (client's EU_West_1) generates links that don't work, info from S3 when i try to download object right after creating an URL:

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Request has expired</Message>
   <X-Amz-Expires>600</X-Amz-Expires>
   <Expires>2016-05-26T09:32:44Z</Expires>
   <ServerTime>2016-05-26T09:33:03Z</ServerTime>
```

As you can see, x-amz-expires was set to 600 seconds, but expires tag says object was expired immediately.

Is it a problem with 
**GeneratePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration** that calculates incorrect expiration time ?

that's my code to set expiration time:

```
    Date expiration =  new Date();
    expiration.setTime(expiration.getTime() + 1000 * 600);
    GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest = new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(bucketName, key);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setMethod(HttpMethod.GET);
    generatePresignedUrlRequest.setExpiration(expiration);
    URL url = s3client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);
```

Looks like both servers return the same time. that's the response from two different EC2 servers connected to two different S3 servers, from the same area. One has a expire set to 4, second to 4000 (to be able to download resource right after creating a link).

Response from server working correctly:

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Request has expired</Message>
   <X-Amz-Expires>4</X-Amz-Expires>
   <Expires>2016-05-31T09:54:04Z</Expires>
   <ServerTime>2016-05-31T11:00:17Z</ServerTime>
```

response from server with presigned URL problem:

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Request has expired</Message>
   <X-Amz-Expires>4000</X-Amz-Expires>
   <Expires>2016-05-31T10:49:54Z</Expires>
   <ServerTime>2016-05-31T11:00:07Z</ServerTime>
```

both links created in the same time (with a few seconds difference for page refresh)

Answer (score 5):

Signature V4 (unlike V2) does not rely on the signature generation code to do the time math to figure out the expiration time.

Generating a V4 signature (as you are doing) requires that you know what time it is *now*, and include that value as `X-Amz-Date`.  AWS then does the math on their side.  "Hey, this guy says he signed it 11 minutes ago, and it's only good for 10 minutes... denied!"

Check the clock on the machine generating the signature.

Comment: so it's an issue with Amazon SDK ?  (I've added code that sets expiration time to the question)
how to get time from S3 server ? (and calculate difference?)

Comment: No, it looks like it's an issue with the clock on your server being wrong.  Set the clock correctly, and you'll be good. `sudo apt-get install ntp`.  If you examine the `X-Amz-Date` in the signed URL -- which *should be* the time when you actually signed it -- and it's several minutes old, this confirms the problem.

Comment: both servers have the same time (returned in error xml) :
<ServerTime>2016-05-31T08:30:50Z</ServerTime>     
<ServerTime>2016-05-31T08:30:35Z</ServerTime>

Comment: That is not the "server time" under discussion.  That is the server time at the S3 server, so, of course that will be correct.  I am referring to the clock on the server where your code is running, generating signatures.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the below article to sync your time( between ec2 and s3)
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/keeping-time-with-amazon-time-sync-service/

we need to use a service called [chrony](https://chrony.tuxfamily.org/).
its a versatile implementation on ntp and a bit more accurate and accomodate leap seconds.

Use below information to troubleshoot:

you can know the time in current linux machine using `date` command.

`X-Amz-Date` tells you when your url was signed in your ec2 or machine where the code is running.
In the response,

```
<Expires>2016-05-31T10:49:54Z</Expires>
<ServerTime>2016-05-31T11:00:07Z</ServerTime>
```

Expires tell when the signature expired based on the X-Amz-Expires and ServerTime tells the time on the s3 server when the request was received.

Answer (score 0):

try using this if you in javascript

```
S3.getSignedUrlPromise('getObject', {
            Bucket: s3Bucket,
            Key: files[0],
            Expires: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7,
        })
```

Comment: Please add more explanation on what this code could resolve the problem that the poster is facing.